# scrollTop not working once clicked on link with other jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have a link with a functionality to dissapear a certain div and open another div. I would like also to add the functionality of scrollTop to the top but it's not responding... I think the code is perfect but maybe I'm missing something...

JQUERY:

```
   // Effect to scroll top NOT WORKING
   $('.bio').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

    /* Open and closing feature on the about/faq */

    //When button is clicked
    $('.text-btn').on('click', function(e) {

      //Prevent url from changing
      e.preventDefault();

      //Find current popup based on data-popup attribute
      var thisInfo = $('.info-' + $(this).data('info'));

      //Hide all other popups
      $('.info').not(thisInfo).fadeOut(0, function(){
        thisInfo.fadeIn(400);
      });

      //Show this popup
    });
```

HTML:

```
<section class="content-block scroll-pane">
                    <article class="content-post">
                        <div class="info info-1" id="info-1">
                            <p>CEPODS creates commercial &amp; residential environments using shipping containers. Our aim is to create a community of enthusiast with each build of our unique modern designs.</p>
                            <p>CEPODS are seen as efficient and effective pod styled units, when compared to other typical commercial spaces such as brick &amp; mortar, food trucks, tent rentals or temporary (pop-up) stores.</p>
                            <p>CEPODS modern design standards are ideal for anyone interested in operating, marketing, advertising or expanding their presence by using innovative alternative commercial space with shipping containers. The ideal CEPODS clients -are small to large businesses, start-up, pop-up, 2nd store, test retail outlet, and advertising & marketing platforms. Our client base is also expanded to residential and lodging enthusiasts. Many more all welcome.</p>
                            <p>CEPODS expertise is based in architecture, engineering, design/build, real estate, marketing, retail sales and small business management. Our team of professionals shares the same common passion; produce high quality modern design builds.</p>
                            <h1>
                                <a href="#" class="text-btn bio" id="info-2-link" data-info="2">Bio<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
                            </h1>
                        </div>

                        <div class="info info-2" id="info-2">
                            <h1>Micro Spaces LLC</h1>
                            <p>Executive Member: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="1">TIMOTHY DUNLAP/TIAN MAO</a></p>
                            <p>Executive Member: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="2">ANDREW HAGUE II</a></p>
                            <p>Director of Engineering: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="3">RICK DE LA GUARDIA</a></p>
                            <p>Project Architect: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="4">IBRAHIM GREENIDGE</a></p>
                            <h1>
                                <a href="#" class="text-btn bio" id="info-1-link" data-info="1">about<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine when I run it.

Have you enclosed your jQuery in `$(document).ready()`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Effect to scroll top NOT WORKING
    $('.bio').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });

    /* Open and closing feature on the about/faq */

    //When button is clicked
    $('.text-btn').on('click', function (e) {

        //Prevent url from changing
        e.preventDefault();

        //Find current popup based on data-popup attribute
        var thisInfo = $('.info-' + $(this).data('info'));

        //Hide all other popups
        $('.info').not(thisInfo).fadeOut(0, function () {
            thisInfo.fadeIn(400);
        });

        //Show this popup
    });
});
```

Otherwise, your propblem is probably somewhere else on the page. Does your console give you any error?

Comment: The whole file is under "$(window).load(function()". All the rest of the jQ commands are working... I tried to change it to document(ready) and it still does not work. At the console I get an error but it has nothing to do with this... Its an error of a fontello font.I do not get why the scrolling is not acting, the jquery below is working. I tried also to insert the same class name as the other function and it still does not scroll to the top. ANy ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, since your code is working for me. Try creating an empty page and only move the sections above there. See if it works then. If so, you can move on to the rest of the code and look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Strangely enough it worked when I chenged from chrome to firefox. Maybe some cache issue...